# Close and Reopen jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, gallery

I've made a gallery plugin which has some `.on ('mouseenter'` , `.on ('mouseleave` and `.on ('click` events (for graphic effects) on divs appended by the plugin self. I need to close and reopen this plugin multiple times without refreshing. On its close the whole plugin html needs to be erased so I can call it back the same way I called it first time:

```
$('#triggerButton').on ('click', function () {    
    $('#Gallery').galleryPlugin();
});
```

So, what do I need to place in the plugin's script when the close button is clicked to erase everything (html and events) and prevent leaving traces etc?

```
$('#CloseGallery').on ('click', function () { 
   // erase everything 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See jquery unbind function.  This will remove the events.

And depending on what html you want removed you can use jquery empty

http://api.jquery.com/empty/

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this, though the next times I open the plugin I get graphic errors. Like some fadeOut 's (inside a click event listener) are not executed. I also tried to place a console.log and I noticed that it logs it many times. (the third time I reopen it, it prints 3 logs row). what can it be?